# How to create a calculated attribute in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

i have a table in sql "empleado", from which, one of the attributes I want it be calculated.

This is the code:

```
create table empleado (
    dni char(9) not null,
    contrasena varchar (20) not null,
    nombre varchar (30) not null,
    apellidos varchar (60) not null,
    direccion varchar (80) not null,
    telefono char (9) not null,
    tipo varchar(30) not null,
    fechaIngreso date not null,
    antiguedad Integer as getdate()-fechaIngreso, 
    salario real not null check (salario >0),

    primary key (dni)
);
```

The attribute antiguedad must be the actual date - "fechaIngreso" in days. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  MySQL does not support `getdate()`, computed columns, or check constraints.  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: I am using ProsgreSQL, i think it is mysql

Comment: . . Postgres is distinct from both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.  You can do what you want with a computed column in SQL Server:

```
create table empleado (
    dni char(9) not null,
    contrasena varchar (20) not null,
    nombre varchar (30) not null,
    apellidos varchar (60) not null,
    direccion varchar (80) not null,
    telefono char (9) not null,
    tipo varchar(30) not null,
    fechaIngreso date not null,
    antiguedad as (cast(getdate() - fechaIngreso as int)), 
    salario real not null check (salario > 0),
    primary key (dni)
);
```

In MySQL, you would use a view to do the same thing.

Comment: it must be mysql because with your solutio it says to me the followinh :

Answer (score 0):

```
create table empleado (
    dni char(9) not null,
    contrasena varchar (20) not null,
    nombre varchar (30) not null,
    apellidos varchar (60) not null,
    direccion varchar (80) not null,
    telefono char (9) not null,
    tipo varchar(30) not null,
    fechaIngreso date not null,
    antiguedad Integer as DATEDIFF(dd,fechaIngreso, getdate())
    salario real not null check (salario >0),

    primary key (dni)
);
```